# How does ASP:NET send the parameters to Actions properly?

Tags: asp.net, post

I have a page that performs post requests. And there is an action for it to take some action according to taken requests.

First, Delete.cshtml located under the Expense View.

```
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<form method="post" asp-action="DeleteExpense">
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3">
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>*@
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Delete Expense</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label asp-for="Amount"></label>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input asp-for="Name" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input asp-for="Amount" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

The prior code takes a post request and redirects another action that deletes the entry correctly. And it's seen as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeleteExpense(int Id)
{
    var obj = _db.Expenses.Find(Id);
    _db.Expenses.Remove(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

We're sending some package of information to our DeleteExpense, but how does it extract the corresponding parameter which is specified in the function signature? I mean If I changed it such as Expense expense in the function signature, it would accept it again correctly. This confuses me that whether the extraction of information out of request is done by ASP.NET under the hood with respect to the parameter specified in the action or it is handled in the HTML Side or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is Expense which contains id so say the parameter you take in to DeleteExpense action action is of type Expense then asp.net core will automatically populate the data of it. or say you want to pass in the id in the url you can do

asp-route-id tag helper and it will populate the int id parameter.

You can read some more about this in the asp.net core documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-5.0